# Finding highest numbered duplicate file names in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a tool on my website to upload files, and when it does the file names are stored in the database. The files are then transferred to a separate server.

So when I upload, I need to check if there are any files with the same name in the database. If there are, I need to append a number inside parentheses to the end of the file(like Windows does for duplicate files).

However, I'm having trouble finding out just *which* number to append.

Here's the TSQL procedure I was using for a while:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getDuplicateCloudEntry]
(
@file_name nvarchar(75),
@file_ext nvarchar(6)
   )
   AS

DECLARE @iHighestDuplicate as integer = 0

--Extracts the number inside of the parentheses of the file name if there's a match
--If there's a duplicate but it's not numbered, don't return anything and the procedure will return a 0 later to let you know there is one duplicate but it is unnumbered
SELECT TOP 1 @iHighestDuplicate =  SUBSTRING(file_name,LEN(@file_name) + 2, len([file_name]) - len(@file_name) - len(@file_ext) -2) FROM tblCloud WHERE file_name LIKE @file_name + '%' + @file_ext
AND (len([file_name]) - len(@file_name) - len(@file_ext) -2) > 0
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(file_name,LEN(@file_name) + 2, len([file_name]) - len(@file_name) - len(@file_ext) -2) as int) Desc

IF @iHighestDuplicate = 0 BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblCloud WHERE file_name LIKE @file_name + '%' + @file_ext) BEGIN
    --there is a duplicate so return 0
    --.vb portion will add 1 to it and append it
        SELECT 0 as HighestDuplicate
    END 
    --if no return then do nothing
END ELSE BEGIN
    --there is more than one duplicate and we will grab the highest number appended
    Select @iHighestDuplicate as HighestDuplicate
END
```

The file_name in the database includes the extension(e.g. "Test.pdf"), and the @file_ext passed in includes the period (e.g. ".pdf").

The problem with this is that sometimes it will find a match on the file name when it's not actually a complete duplicate since there are additional characters. For example if there is a file named "Testing.pdf" in the database, this will find a match on the input "Test.pdf". It will then try to extract the number from "Testing.pdf" and get an error.

Is there a better way for me to do this, or a solution to my problem matching file names?

Comment: why not simply use an id field? `filename + record id` is already trivially obtainable from the table, rather than having to parse ALL similar files and try to pick out the max number.

Comment: What if somebody tries to upload a file legitimately called `Test(14).pdf`? Can you do an MD5 or some other hash for creating a unique filename?

Comment: @MarcB That is a brilliant idea and I can't believe I didn't think of just doing something simple like that. Thank you!

Comment: Regardless of what you append, you need to have a plan for coping with hitting an existing file. A couple of ways to eliminate the issue: (1) Store the file content "in" the database. There are performance and administration issues with this approach. (B) Store the file _name_ in the database, but name the actual file with the _id_ from the database. This allows, for example, two users to upload `Foo42.xml` while keeping them separate. I've typically used an identity column for the id and nested directories to reduce performance issues, e.g. `123456` becomes `\12\34\56.dat`.